# A special variation of the Multiple Choice Knapsack (MCK) problem

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, reference-request, np-complete

So, in an ordinary MCK problem, there is just one weight constraint, namely, the weight constraint of  the knapsack. I have encountered a special variation of the MCK problem, in which there are more than one weight constraints. Conceptually, this can be thought of as if there are multiple chambers in the knapsack, and each chamber has its own weight constraint. An assumption can be made that all the chambers have the same weight constraint. When taking an item from a class, this item will occupy just one chamber, or it can occupy more than one chambers. Everything else is exactly a MCK problem.

I was wondering if anyone came across similar problems before? If you did, could you please point me to some literature on its analysis or approximation solutions?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by an item can  occupy multiple chambers. What do the weight constraints do then? if an item can be in multiple chambers than just solve the MCK without the extra constraints and then assign the chambers fraction of items until they are full.  is the difference in the objective function?

Comment: An item occupies multiple chambers means that the same item is replicated and each selected chamber store one whole copy of the item. This is because replicating the same content to different chambers will result in different values.

Comment: Just google "Multiple Choice Knapsack Problem" and you should get some references.

Comment: But how is it then separate from just a number of MCK problems. Since the items are not unique. couldn't i just solve the MCK problem for each compartment? or is their a  weight constraint for total weight?

Comment: Well the items are unique. However, when they are replicated and stored in different chambers, the total value will depend on which chambers you used. For example, scenario 1: item $n$ is stored in chamber 1 and 2; scenario 2: item $n$ is stored in chamber 3 and 4. the values gained in scenario 1 and 2 are different, though they carry the same amount of weight.